# How can I log the body request and response in Apache Server only for some URLs?

Tags: apache-2.4, logging, apache2

I have to debug an apache server request / response body. I intend to use mod_dump_io. How can I log only specific request?

I'm searching for any kind of filter or allow-list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dumpio.html the only directive that is not a server config scope is LogLevel. Put `LogLevel dumpio:trace7` inside a `<Location>` stanza.

Comment: I beg to differ, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#loglevel indicates LogLevel has a context of `server config, virtual host, directory`

I was googling for help because like many others, my dumpio wasn't producing output to the `error.log`